# System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile caues cpu leak

Tags: .net, performance, linq

Hi I have a rule engine mechanism,in background I create dynamic linq queries and set my values and execute it.But sometimes I have cpu  leak and when I check the waiting point it hangs under ,Can I make a optimization without making major code change

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler:Compile
 -->
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod:CreateDelegate method

 public Func<T, bool> CompileRule<T>(Rule r)
        {
            var paramUser = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            Expression expr = GetExpressionForRule<T>(r, paramUser);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, paramUser).Compile();
        }


   Expression GetExpressionForRule<T>(Rule r, ParameterExpression param)
        {
            ExpressionType nestedOperator;
            if (ExpressionType.TryParse(r.Operator, out nestedOperator) && nestedOperators.Contains(nestedOperator) && r.Rules != null && r.Rules.Any())
                return BuildNestedExpression<T>(r.Rules, param, nestedOperator);
            else
                return BuildExpr<T>(r, param);
        }

 Expression BuildExpr<T>(Rule r, ParameterExpression param)
        {
            Expression propExpression = null;
            Type propType = null;
            List<Expression> ChildPropertyList = new List<Expression>();

            ExpressionType tBinary;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.MemberName))//check is against the object itself
            {
                propExpression = param;
                propType = propExpression.Type;
            }.......
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a CPU leak.If `Compile()` is slow it means the expression is too big or too comlex. What does `GetExpressionForRule` do and what kind of expression does it create?

Comment: LINQ queries are already dynamic. You can use different expressions in Select, Where etc or append different `.Where()` calls to a query.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis ,I cant because I dont have single query,myqueries and values always change by condition.My sitation is when my cpu is %100 and see waiting threads I see that part System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod:CreateDelegate

Comment: Without knowing what `GetExpressionForRule` one can only guess. If it creates a complex expression, compiling it and executing it can take time. *Simplfying* it will provide greater benefits than compiling the expression

Comment: I add GetExpressionForRule to mq question,it creates a build expression